# MySQL, objects and superclasses

Tags: mysql, oop

I'm having some troubles with designing my website. I'm trying to use OOP design in the way I design my site and using MySQL to store the objects in JSON format.

So I'm creating a MySQL table inside my database. The table is going to contain a primary key (PK) and what I call page type (pageType, ex: homePage, aMessage, aTutorial, etc). This means that I will have serval different pages that have different page formats (pageFormats, ex: headerArea, contentArea, footerArea, etc). So depending on the pageType object that was requested, the query would then go to pageFormat table to retrieve the desired divs.

So for example, we have a AJAX request that says the pageType is set to homePage. The request would then go to the pageFormat table and see which divs the homePage is allowed and then return them. I then of course would write them to the document and continue on loading the page with desired content and so forth.

I am just having trouble going from my UML / documentation to actual development of this idea. So if someone could help me with this it'd be greatly appreciated. The trouble that is most difficult for me to understand is that in MySQL database I have is setting up the table for pageType and pageFormat.

The returned types would be in JSON form so the scripts of my page would be able to format them correctly. So that leads me to my second question of what is the best way to store JSON objects in a MySQL table that are going to be divs? Would it be TINYTEXT? Because I don't plan on having large amount of text in there?

Then my last question would be, what would be the best table type? I'm having trouble with selecting this as well.

I have referenced http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html for the table types to try and help me though I'm still unsure.

I also have been reading http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#BasicConcepts to understand how to implement relational databases and mapping objects to them. Is there any other good reads that I should look into?

Thanks for any help / direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to objects data as JSON-documents, I recommend you to use a NoSQL database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) instead of MySQL, since they allow you to use JSON directly to store data.

With MySQL, the most common approach is to use a [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) layer to avoid the impedance between a relational database management system and a object-oriented language. By storing a JSON-like object in a RDMS, you are forcing your dynamic schema document to fit in a scalar value, which in my opinion is not the best solution at all.

Comment: Ah... I mean I was having trouble with conceptualizing how to fit objects into MySQL. Going to check out the recommended MongoDB and CouchDB because that sounds like what I am looking for. Hopefully I can report back later tonight to let you know if this will provide me with the solution I desire. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Alright, so I've been looking into the MongoDB and CouchDB but sadly my shared hosting service (hostgator) does not support these. I'm looking at an article http://blog.pnapieralski.com/mongodb/how-to-setup-mongodb-php-extension-on-shared-hosting/ by using this. Would you suggest that or is there a better alternative?

Comment: So I've looked more into trying to get mongoDB to run on hostgator and I've been hitting a lot of walls and don't see this as a solution. Is there a good cheap hosting service? The website I'm looking to make is for my resume but also to provide tutorials. I'm really not looking to spend more than $10 a month for this kind of hosting.

Comment: @pmac89 I don't know the specific problems with your hosting service, but I think these issues are too localized. The solution of your problem shouldn't depend on such details - you can always look at what is offered by other hosting providers.

Comment: Ya, I just looked into it and was seeing if any had suggestions. Hostgator does not have a work around to get the mongoDB working. I am looking into using WebFaction as my hosting provider to be able to get mongoDB and still have the features I need which comes in at the price point I desire. Is there any other services I should look at?

Comment: @pmac89 There are some sites which provide free MongoDB storage, like [mongolab](https://mongolab.com) or [alwaysdata.com](https://www.alwaysdata.com/). A quick search on Google of _free mongoDB hosting_ can give you more alternatives apart from these two.

Comment: I was talking about web hosting services that provide the MongoDB tool or a web hosting service that provides a simple way to hook into a Mongo Database.